# How to fix Error: invalid address

Tags: remix, metamask, contract-debugging, error

I am trying to run the smart contract listed in the documentation here https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#subcurrency-example

```
    // Sends an amount of newly created coins to an address
    // Can only be called by the contract creator
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }
```

But every time I try to execute the `mint` function, it fails with the following error:

> transact to Coin.mint errored: Error encoding arguments: Error:
> invalid address (argument="address", value="1000000",
> code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.4.0) (argument=null,
> value="1000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.4.0)

I am using the Remix IDE integrated with my MetaMask.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: What are u giving as input ? That function take 2 arguments

Comment: i am passing a number to the mint function via the remix UI

Comment: you need to pass 2 arguments. this function take 2 , first the address and then the amount of tokens

Comment: F5 - update your navigator, maybe REMIX is taken a cached ABI instead the last compiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error message and logs it looks like you're passing invalid arguments ---

> (argument="address", value="1000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.4.0)

The address argument expects an address type argument, but you're passing a number (1000000) instead.

> (argument=null, value="1000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.4.0)

The second parameter should have had an argument type "amount" but it appears to be null.

Looks like you need to double-check the parameter-argument pairs that you're passing.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while trying to pass an address type argument in mocha tests with value of `null`, the solution was to set the value to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, which is the equivalent of `address(0)` in solidity.

So from this

```
  contract.mint({
    id: 0,
    name: 'Luger',
    kind: 'weapon',
    price: 1,
    owner: null
  })
```

To this

```
  contract.mint({
    id: 0, // temporary
    name: 'Luger',
    kind: 'weapon',
    price: 1,
    owner: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
  })
```